Need help in optimizing this simulation loop in webots
I am Running this simulation in webots (a robotics simulation software) using python.
I eventually want to train an actor-critic network using the depth map generated by a depth-estimation model.
The code implements a simple altitude PID controller for the drone and code to estimate depth from the images taken from the drone's camera.
current inference time for the depth-estimation model is around 32ms with a GPU. and the simulation is running at 25% of real-time speed (takes 4 seconds to simulate 1 second of events).
I am sure when the actor-critic network is added, the sim speed will slow down even more.
Help in identifying bottlenecks and clearing them will be appreciated.
This is the class that defines all the Drone functionalities:
from controller import Robot, Camera, GPS, InertialUnit, Motor, LED
from typing import Tuple, List

class Mavic:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the Robot
        self.drone = Robot()
        self.timestep = int(self.drone.getBasicTimeStep())

        # Enable Camera
        self.camera = self.drone.getDevice("camera")
        self.camera.enable(self.timestep)

        # Enable IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit)
        self.imu = self.drone.getDevice("inertial unit")
        self.imu.enable(self.timestep)

        # Enable Gyroscope
        self.gyro = self.drone.getDevice("gyro")
        self.gyro.enable(self.timestep)

        # Enable GPS
        self.gps = self.drone.getDevice("gps")
        self.gps.enable(self.timestep)

        # Initialize Propellers (Motors)
        motor_names = [
            "front left propeller", "front right propeller", 
            "rear left propeller", "rear right propeller"
        ]
        
        self.motors = [self.drone.getDevice(motor_name) for motor_name in motor_names]
        
        for motor in self.motors:
            motor.setPosition(float('inf'))  # Set motors to velocity control mode
            motor.setVelocity(0.0)  # Initialize motor velocity to zero

    def get_imu_values(self) -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
        """Returns the roll, pitch, and yaw values from the IMU."""
        return self.imu.getRollPitchYaw()

    def get_gps_values(self) -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
        """Returns the x, y, and z coordinates from the GPS."""
        return self.gps.getValues()

    def get_gyro_values(self) -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
        """Returns the angular velocity around x, y, and z axes from the gyro."""
        return self.gyro.getValues()

    def get_time(self) -> float:
        """Returns the current simulation time."""
        return self.drone.getTime()

    def set_rotor_speed(self, speeds: Tuple[float, float, float, float]) -> None:
        """Sets the velocity for each rotor."""
        for motor, speed in zip(self.motors, speeds):
            motor.setVelocity(speed)

    def get_image(self) -> List[List[List[int]]]:
        return self.camera.getImage()
    
    def step_robot(self) -> int:
        """Increments the simulation step."""
        return self.drone.step(self.timestep)

The simulation code:
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
from mavic import Mavic
from constants import (
    K_VERTICAL_THRUST,
    K_ROLL_P, 
    K_PITCH_P, 
    MAX_SIMULATION_TIME
)
from loguru import logger
from utils import calculate_pid_altitude, process_image, clamp_motor_speed
from model import DepthModel

def main():
    mavic = Mavic()
    logger.info("Drone object created")

    altitudes = [1 + i / 2 for i in range(5)]
    current_altitude_idx = 0
    target_altitude = altitudes[current_altitude_idx]
    change_time = mavic.get_time()
    
    integral_altitude_error = 0.0
    previous_altitude_error = 0.0
    timestep_seconds = mavic.timestep / 1000.0

    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    depth_model = DepthModel().to(device)
    depth_model.load_state_dict(torch.load("weights/TFL_5_3.pth", weights_only=True, map_location=device))
    depth_model.eval()
    logger.info("Depth Model Loaded")

    while mavic.step_robot() <= MAX_SIMULATION_TIME:
        current_time = mavic.get_time()
        if current_time >= MAX_SIMULATION_TIME:
            break

        if current_time - change_time >= 10.0:
            current_altitude_idx = (current_altitude_idx + 1) % len(altitudes)
            target_altitude = max(altitudes[current_altitude_idx], 0.5)
            change_time = current_time
            logger.info(f"New altitude: {target_altitude}")

        roll, pitch, _ = mavic.get_imu_values()
        _, _, z = mavic.get_gps_values()
        roll_velocity, pitch_velocity, _ = mavic.get_gyro_values()

        roll_input = K_ROLL_P * np.clip(roll, -1.0, 1.0) + roll_velocity
        pitch_input = K_PITCH_P * np.clip(pitch, -1.0, 1.0) + pitch_velocity
        yaw_input = 0.0

        vertical_input, integral_altitude_error, previous_altitude_error = calculate_pid_altitude(
            target_altitude, z, timestep_seconds, integral_altitude_error, previous_altitude_error
        )

        base_thrust = K_VERTICAL_THRUST + vertical_input
        motor_speeds = [
            clamp_motor_speed(base_thrust - roll_input + pitch_input - yaw_input),
            clamp_motor_speed(base_thrust + roll_input + pitch_input + yaw_input),
            clamp_motor_speed(base_thrust - roll_input - pitch_input + yaw_input),
            clamp_motor_speed(base_thrust + roll_input - pitch_input - yaw_input)
        ]

        mavic.set_rotor_speed((motor_speeds[0], -motor_speeds[1], -motor_speeds[2], motor_speeds[3]))

        raw_image = mavic.camera.getImage()
        image_width, image_height = mavic.camera.getWidth(), mavic.camera.getHeight()
        img_tensor = process_image(raw_image, image_width, image_height, device)

        with torch.no_grad():
            depth = depth_model(img_tensor)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


The utils.py file:
from constants import *

import numpy as np
import torch
import cv2

def calculate_pid_altitude(target, current, timestep, integral, prev_error):
    # Calculates the PID control output for altitude adjustment
    error = target - current
    integral += error * timestep
    derivative = (error - prev_error) / timestep
    pid_output = (K_VERTICAL_P * error) + (K_VERTICAL_I * integral) + (K_VERTICAL_D * derivative)
    return pid_output, integral, error

def clamp_motor_speed(input_speed):
    # Clamps the motor speed within the allowable range to prevent excessive values
    return max(min(input_speed, MAX_MOTOR_VELOCITY), -MAX_MOTOR_VELOCITY)

def process_image(raw_image, width, height, device):
    # Converts a raw image to a PyTorch tensor after resizing and moving to the specified device
    img_array = np.frombuffer(raw_image, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 4))[:, :, :3]
    img_resized = cv2.resize(img_array, (120, 200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(img_resized).float().permute(2, 0, 1).unsqueeze(0).to(device)
    return img_tensor


The pytorch model:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class UpSample(nn.Sequential):
    def __init__(self, skip_input, output_features):
        super(UpSample, self).__init__()
        self.convA = nn.Conv2d(
            skip_input, output_features, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.leakyreluA = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)
        self.convB = nn.Conv2d(
            output_features, output_features, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1
        )
        self.leakyreluB = nn.LeakyReLU(0.2)

    def forward(self, x, concat_with):
        up_x = F.interpolate(
            x,
            size=[concat_with.size(2), concat_with.size(3)],
            mode="bilinear",
            align_corners=True,
        )
        return self.leakyreluB(
            self.convB(
                self.leakyreluA(self.convA(torch.cat([up_x, concat_with], dim=1)))
            )
        )


class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_features=2208, decoder_width=0.5):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        features = int(num_features * decoder_width)

        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(
            num_features, features, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=1
        )

        self.up1 = UpSample(
            skip_input=features // 1 + 384, output_features=features // 2
        )
        self.up2 = UpSample(
            skip_input=features // 2 + 192, output_features=features // 4
        )
        self.up3 = UpSample(
            skip_input=features // 4 + 96, output_features=features // 8
        )
        self.up4 = UpSample(
            skip_input=features // 8 + 96, output_features=features // 16
        )

        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(features // 16, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

    def forward(self, features):
        x_block0, x_block1, x_block2, x_block3, x_block4 = (
            features[3],
            features[4],
            features[6],
            features[8],
            features[11],
        )
        x_d0 = self.conv2(x_block4)
        x_d1 = self.up1(x_d0, x_block3)
        x_d2 = self.up2(x_d1, x_block2)
        x_d3 = self.up3(x_d2, x_block1)
        x_d4 = self.up4(x_d3, x_block0)
        return self.conv3(x_d4)


class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        import torchvision.models as models

        self.original_model = models.densenet161(
            weights=models.DenseNet161_Weights.DEFAULT
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        features = [x]
        for k, v in self.original_model.features._modules.items():
            features.append(v(features[-1]))
        return features


class DepthModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DepthModel, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = Decoder()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.decoder(self.encoder(x))

This screen shot is from the simulation software (ignore the code at the right):
(https://i.sstatic.net/xLtoA7iI.png)
In the purple box showing elapsed simulation time, the 0.25x shows that the whole simulation is running 25% slower than real-time speed.
